# update database rows by $_POST data with key as id for row

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following $_POST data received from the user

```
url[3] = "beheer"
name[3] = "knowledge"
parent_id[3] = "0"

url[4] = "asd"
name[4] = "adasdas"
parent_id[4] = "0"

url[5] = "asdasd"
name[5] = "asdsadasd"
parent_id[5] = "0"
```

Where the key is the id for each data.
I want to loop through all the data and update the rows

this will execute for example:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET url = 'beheer', name = 'knowledge', parent_id='0' WHERE id = 3");
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: So does this query not work the way you're expecting it to work?

Comment: Are indexes (url, name, parent_id) always the same, or should it adapt to any index given?

Comment: @ChrisWillard, the query example is the query I want to get out of the program logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that :

```
   foreach ($url as $key => $value)
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET url = '$value', name = '$name[$key]', parent_id='$parent_id[$key]' WHERE id = '$key'");
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the easiest way to solve it would be to use an associative array instead. So you have one variable, called $values, and then add your names to that like this:

```
$values[0]['url']
$values[0]['name']
$values[0]['parent_id']

$values[1]['url']
$values[1]['name']
$values[1]['parent_id']

$values[2]['url']
$values[2]['name']
$values[2]['parent_id']
```

This will enable you to iterate over the array using a foreach loop like so.

```
foreach($values AS $value) {
  $url = $value['url'];
  $name = $value['name'];
  $parent_id = $value['parent_id'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO table (url,name,parent_id) VALUES ('$url','$name','$parent_id')";
}

$sql->query($query);
```

This is of course a simple example, but it should help.